# Pytesseract does not extract text from low-quality image

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to extract text from the image:

[image]

I have tried using the below code to extract the text:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
img = "Offers.png"
tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img))
string = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(img), config='--psm 6')
```

I could not extract text. `tex` variable returns an empty string, whereas the `string` variable returns a line of text.

What can I do to extract the complete text from the pamphlet image?

**EDIT 1:**

Since the previously provided image was low quality, I'm now providing some random images from google images with comparatively better quality.

[image: new image 2]

[image: new image 3]

Now when I try to implement the same code above to extract the text, I'm unable to extract the complete text.

**EDIT 2:**

```
img = cv2.imread('sale-banner-template-design_74379-121.jpg',0)
thesh, im_bw = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

up_image = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=2,fy=3,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

t = pytesseract.image_to_string(up_image)
```

Comment: Is that the original images that you are trying to get text from? That image is very low quality.

Comment: Yes, this is the image

Comment: The image is really small, I doubt you will be able to extract text from that version. An higher resolution version should have no problem.

Comment: @bracco23 I've now added two new images of reasonable quality. And again I couldn't extract the whole text in pamphlet image.

Comment: I had the same issue. I end up cutting the specific section I want to recognize in a new image and then it works. I tried easyOCR and will work better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Removing colour, unnessary input and upscaling the image size. This helps tesseract a significant amount. You can do all of this with PIL and its various modules

Comment: I've done the above preprocessing with opencv, but still the output is same.